# Kali doesn't seem to have ~/.bash_profile file, what's the profile file called in Kali?

Tags: kali-linux

am on a Kali box and ~/.bash_profile doesn't seems to work in Kali. Is it called by some other filename in Kali?

Comment: The title says "doesn't seem to have" (it's not there), the question "doesn't seem to work" (it's there, but has no effect) – which is it?

Comment: I think it was not there by default, a script tried creating it and now its there. But doesn't seems to work.

Comment: I think ~/.bash_profile is not the file name in kali distro

Answer (score 3):

The file `~/.bash_profile` will be used by the `bash` shell if it is invoked as a login shell.

If the file does not exist (it does not need to exist), then it may be created by a user.

If the shell is not `bash`, or if the `bash` shell is not a login shell (such as it won't be if it's used for running a script or starting an interactive non-login shell session), then the file will not be used.

Other shells may read `~/.profile` for login shells, and `bash` does this too if `~/.bash_profile` does not exist.

To figure out what shell you are using for your login shell, use

```
getent passwd username
```

where `username` is your username.  The login shell will be the last `:`-delimited item in the resulting line.

Example:

```
$ getent passwd myself
myself:*:1000:1000:Kusalananda,,,:/home/myself:/usr/local/bin/zsh
```

This means my login shell is `zsh`.

Note that your choice of Linux distribution has very little (nothing) to do with whether `~/.bash_profile` is used or not.  It is your choice of login shell that determines this.

Comment: its showing bash for me

Comment: I know about this though. 

There is another qucick way to check `echo $0`

Comment: @Sam Could you clarify the question with what you are trying to do and what actually happens, please? Note that `echo $0` would show you what the _current_ shell was, most of the time, not necessarily what your login shell is.

Comment: @Sam Also note that this `~/.bash_profile` file is only ever read when the shell _starts_.  Changes to the file would not gain effect until the next login shell starts.

Comment: okay, I want to update ~/.bash_profile file I know its there in ubuntu but not sure about kali. I ran someone's script in my kali box which was meant to be ran on a  ubuntu machine. That script either created ~/.bash_profile or overwrited it. Am not sure which of the two it did because I dont know if that file existed before running that script or not.